# How to find the the basis of $W^{\bot}$ if $W=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,0,0), (0,0,1,1)\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

> Find the the basis of $W^{\bot}$ if $W=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,0,0), (0,0,1,1)\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ using Gram-Shmidt process (GSP).

Let $u_1=(1,1,0,0)$ and $u_2=(0,0,1,1)$.

According to GSP $u_1$ stays as is.

Regarding $u_2$:
$$
u_2=u_2-\frac{u_2u_1}{||u_1||}u_1
$$
But $u_2u_1=0$ so $u_2=u_2$. Which means that $W=W^{\bot}$ which is not true as $W \oplus W^{\bot}=\mathbb R^4$ and the answer is that the basis for $W^{\bot}$ is $\{(1,-1,0,0),(0,0,1,-1)\}$.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You need a full basis to start with. Can you extend $u_1,u_2$ to a basis $u_1, u_2, v_3,v_4$? From there you run Gram-Schmidt. What happened above is correct. $u_2$ won't change because it is already orthogonal to $u_1$.

Comment: You are doing it all wrong! In the first place what you have done is that you have orthogonalized the basis of the subspace. Now you have extend the basis of the subspace to the whole space ,. then orthogonalize that basis and then take the other two elements removing $u_{1}$ and your new $u_{2}$. It comes out that the given basis for the subspace is already orthogonal. So you are getting the same $u_{2}$ as our new $u_{2}$.

Comment: @KenDuna why do I need the full basis? Also I found that the basis of $W$ can be extended if I add 2 more vectors and I will get the following basis: $$u_1=(1,1,0,0)\\u_2=(0,1,0,0)\\u_3=(0,0,1,0)\\u_4=(0,0,1,1)$$. If I calculate $u'_2$ then $u'_2=u_2-\frac{u_2u_1}{||u_1||^2}u-1=(-1/2,1/2,0,0)$. I don't think that's still the right direction.

Comment: @Yos $-\frac{1}{2}(-1/2,1/2,0,0) = (1,-1,0,0)$ which is one of the vectors given by the book. What you did is fine, there is no unique basis of $W^\perp$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ such that two vector are a basis of $W$. Then if you apply the Gram-Schmidt first to the basis of $W$ you get a new orthonormal basis of $W$.

Then continue applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure to the other two vectors and you get a basis for $W^\bot$.

Because there are a lot of boring calculations you can use wolfram-alpha or some other CAS for this common task. By example take a look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Orthogonalize%5B%7B%7B1,1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,1%7D,%7B0,0,1,0%7D,%7B1,0,0,0%7D%7D%5D).

Comment: I don't understand why it's not enough to just apply GSP to the basis of $W$. When you say "if you apply the Gram-Schmidt first to the basis of $W$ you get a new orthonormal basis of $W$.". Aren't we done here, isn't this the orthonormal basis $W^{\bot}$?

Comment: If you apply GSP to a basis of $W$ you get an orthonormal basis of $W$, not of $W^\bot$. You need a basis of $W$ extended to a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ to find an orthonormal basis of $W^\bot$ after applying GSP to it. The GSP what it does is transform a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ to an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^4$. Thus if you first transform the basis of $W$ the the other two orthonormal vectors are, by definition, an orthonormal basis of $W^\bot$ because $W\oplus W^\bot=\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix whose rows are $u_1=(1,1,0,0)$ and $u_2=(0,0,1,1)$ can we say that $W^{\bot}$ equals the null space of $A$? Then in order to find $W^{\bot}$ I could find the solution to $Ax=0$.

Comment: But such $A$ must be a square matrix because $x\in\Bbb R^4$. In any case Im not sure about how to deal with such matrix to find a basis of $W^\bot$. As the other answer said you can do it faster without using GSP just finding two orthogonal vectors to $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,1)$, that is, an orthogonal basis of $\Bbb R^4$. Then these two other vectors are by definition a basis of $W^\bot$.

Comment: Ok so this is the extended basis for $W$:
$$u_1=(1,1,0,0)\\u_2=(0,1,0,0)\\u_3=(0,0,1,0)\\u_4=(0,0,1,1)$$
Now: 
$$
u_1'=u_1\\
u'_2=u_2-\frac{u_2u_1}{||u_1^2||}u_1=(0,1,0,0)-\frac{1}{2}(1,1,0,0)=(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0)\\
u_3'=u_3-0=(0,0,1,0)\\
u'_4=u_4-(0,0,1,0)=(0,0,0,1)
$$
I didn't normalize them. So how do I choose $W^{\bot}$ from the 4 vectors that I got after GSP?

Comment: Observe that $u_2$ must be $(0,0,1,1)$, not $(0,1,0,0)$, because it hold using the GSP that $$\operatorname{span}(u_1,\ldots,u_j)=\operatorname{span}(u'_1,\ldots,u'_j)$$ for all $j$. Then if you want an orthogonal basis of $W$ you must set $u_2=(0,0,1,1)$. After you orthogonalized the basis then $$W^\bot=\operatorname{span}(u'_3,u'_4)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem without using Gram-Schmidt.

Notice that $(1,-1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,-1)\in W^{\perp}$. Clearly these are linearly independent, by dimension counting and the fact that $W\oplus W^{\perp}\cong \mathbb{R}^4$ we are done.

Comment: Nice trick! Can you explain though why we need to extend the given basis to dim 4 for GSP?

Comment: That is how I would have approached a problem like this, but the question was how to do this with Gram-Schmidt. These "insight" approaches are great for people with experience. However, for someone at the student level, this is probably not something they can come up with themselves. Gram-Schmidt may be a bit of a clunky way to go about this, but it will always work on these sorts of problems.

Comment: @Yos: Doing this with Gram-Schmidt is more or less the same in some sense. You could take the basis $\left\{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\right\}$ for $W$ and extend to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ (which has dimension $4$, so you need to add two vectors which are independent of all previous vectors. Gramm-Schmidt turns this basis into a orthogonal one, thus the two vectors you added are now orthogonal to basis vectors of $W$ and thus belong to $W^{\perp}$. In my answer I just gave two vectors which can easily seen to be orthogonal to $W$ (without GSP) and justified that this is enough.